# Performing Assembler "IDIV" opcode with python

Tags: python, assembly, x86, twos-complement, x86-emulation

I am trying to implement some assembly code with python.
I have the following code -

```
00DF26C7  |. B9 0C000000    MOV ECX,0C
00DF26CC  |. F7F9           IDIV ECX
```

and my registers are -

```
EAX FFFFFEB0
ECX 0000000C
EDX FFFFFFFF
EBX 003CF000
ESP 0053F858
EBP 0053F860
ESI 00000000
```

If EAX is a positive number, then the following python code have exactly the same output as the opcode -

```
int(eax / 0x0c) & 0xffffffff
```

but I can't make it work for a negative eax...
from my understanding the `idiv` opcode uses EDX:EAX, so `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFEB0 / 0x0c`, but even when trying this way I get a wrong result.

Maybe someone know how to implement this opcode?
P.S.
the correct result is - `0xFFFFFFE4`

Comment: `IDIV` is signed hence `0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFEB0` means `-336` so the result is `-28` which is indeed `0xFFFFFFE4`. You will also need to take care of truncating in the proper direction if the remainder is nonzero.

Comment: Python uses arbitrary-precision integers, so you'll need to manually interpret the sign bit unless it has a way to take an integer as a 64-bit two's complement bit-pattern.  Also note that `idiv` truncates towards zero, like C.  IIRC, Python integer division is different.